# Back to Front Eisenstein - number theory

Tags: number-theory, irreducible-polynomials

So I was reading through Springer's Elements of Algebra and it brought up the existence of a 'back to front' version of the criterion.

It goes something like;

Let $f(x) = a(n)x^n +a(n−1)x^{n-1} +\cdots +a(1)x+a(0)$ be a polynomial in
$\mathbb{Z}[x]$. If there is a prime $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that:

- $p|a(i)$ for $i = 1, \dots , n$,
- $p$ does not divide $a(0)$, and
- $p^2$ does not divide $a(n)$,

it follows that $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Now I think we should substitute $x^{-1}$ into the original (regular) Eisenstein criterion, and work through, but I'm having a complete brain freeze for where to start. Any pointers appreciated, and I'm sure I'll feel a lemon when it becomes clear!

Comment: It's the time of year for pomelo. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pomelo

Comment: At the moment the question claims that $p$ simultaneously does and does not divide $a(n)$. Should it maybe say $p^2 \nmid a(n)$?

Comment: Quite right should be p^2, typo on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ The reversal map $\,f(x)\mapsto x^d f(x^{-1}), \ d = \deg f\,$ is a degree-preserving *multiplicative* map hence preserves multiplicative structure, e.g. (ir)reducibility.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $d$ with non-zero constant term. Let $p^\ast(x)=x^d p(1/x)$. Then $p^\ast(x)$ has degree $d$, and $(p^\ast)^\ast(x)=p(x)$. 
Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial with non-zero constant term, and let $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ be polynomials. Then
$$f(x)=g(x)h(x)\quad\text{if and only if}\quad f^\ast(x)=g^\ast(x)h^\ast(x).$$
It follows that $f(x)$ is irreducible if and only if $f^\ast(x)$ is irreducible.

Comment: No, instead of $f^\ast$ I could have used some other notation, the $^\ast$ is just a mapping that takes polynomials with non-zero constant term to polynomials with non-zero constant term. It is a formal way of describing writing the polynomial "backwards." So for example if $p(x)=x^3+5x^2-8x+2$ then $p^\ast(x)=2x^3-8x^2+5x+1$.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, I thought of this afterwards, it's just different notation from what I'm used to. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome. There is as far as I know no established notation for this particular mapping.